# g_main_loop uses 100% CPU

Tags: c++, multithreading, glib, gtkmm

I have built my first application using glibmm. I'm using a lot of threads as it does heavy processing. I have tried to follow the guidelines concerning multithreading, i.e. not doing any GUI updates from other threads than the one where `g_main_loop` is running.

I do a lot of graphics rendering in worker threads but I always only update a `PixBuf` which is later drawn by the widgets `on_draw()` from the main loop.

All was fine as long as the data I render was read from files. When I started streaming data from a server which I render at regular intervals then the problems started.

Every now and then, especially when executing multiple instances of my application simultaneously, I see that the main threads takes 100% CPU time. Running strace on the process shows that `g_main_loop` has ended up in an eternal loop calling `poll`:

```
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 4, 100) = 1 ([{fd=10, revents=POLLIN}])
```

In proc I get this for file-descriptor 10: `10 -> socket:[1132750]`

The poll always returns immediately as file-descriptor 10 has something to offer. This goes on forever so I assume that the file-descriptor is never read. The odd thing is that running 5 applications will almost always lead to all 5 ending up in the infinite poll loop after just a couple of minutes while running only instance one seems to work more than 30 minutes most of the times I try.

Why is this happening and is there any way to debug this?

Comment: Connect a debugger (like `gdb`), create a breakpoint for `poll`, wait for it, collect a backtrace (`bt` in `gdb`), now think why `poll` is called in a first place

Comment: @myaut, I never did pin down the problem using GDB. Why `g_main_loop` went bananas just by calling `queue_draw()` from another thread is still beyond me, it would imo make more sense if that was allowed since it's not really a GUI update, it's just queuing a GUI update.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was that I called `queue_draw()` from one of my worker threads. Given that the function is called "queue", I assumed it would queue a redraw which would later be executed by the `g_main_loop`. As it turned out, this was what broke the `g_main_loop`. I wish `libgtkmm` would have a little more detail about these multithreading restrictions in its reference manual.

My solution, to the problem was adding `Glib::Dispatcher queueRedraw` to my Widget and connecting it to the `queue_draw()` function:

`queueRedraw.connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyWidgetClass::queue_draw))`

Calling `queueRedraw()` signals the main thread to call the `queue_draw()` function.

I don't know if this is the best approach, but it solves the problem.